# Combining data in rows with the same key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

My sql statement looks like this.

```
SELECT fe.AdmSiteID,A.SiteDescription, 
        '' AS SNAP, ''  AS TANF, '' AS Foster, ''   AS FDPIR, ''    AS Homeless, '' AS Migrant, ''  AS Runaway, 
        '' AS HeadStart, '' AS EvenStart, ''    AS DirectCertified,  '' AS NoApplication, '' AS FreeIncome, '' AS ReducedIncome, 
        ''  AS RefusedBenefits,''   AS DeniedIncome, '' AS DeniedVerification,  ''  AS DeniedNotValid, ''   AS TempFreeGrace, ''    AS TempReducedGrace, 
        ''  AS DeniedInactive, ''   AS DNQ, '' AS ExpiredGrace 
FROM FarEligibilityEnrollmentCounts fe 
inner join AdmSites A on fe.AdmSiteID = A.AdmSiteID 
GROUP BY fe.AdmSiteID,A.SiteDescription 
union
select fe.AdmSiteID,A.SiteDescription,sum(PatronCount) as SNAP, ''  AS TANF, '' AS Foster, ''   AS FDPIR, ''    AS Homeless, '' AS Migrant, ''  AS Runaway, 
        '' AS HeadStart, '' AS EvenStart, ''    AS DirectCertified,  '' AS NoApplication, '' AS FreeIncome, '' AS ReducedIncome, 
        ''  AS RefusedBenefits,''   AS DeniedIncome, '' AS DeniedVerification,  ''  AS DeniedNotValid, ''   AS TempFreeGrace, ''    AS TempReducedGrace, 
        ''  AS DeniedInactive, ''   AS DNQ, '' AS ExpiredGrace
        from FarEligibilityEnrollmentCounts fe 
        inner join AdmSites A on fe.AdmSiteID = A.AdmSiteID 
        where fe.FarStudentCaseID = '4FA4AED1-75C9-4CB4-9FF2-102C2D964CC1'
        Group BY fe.AdmSiteID,A.SiteDescription       
union 
select fe.AdmSiteID,A.SiteDescription,'' as SNAP, sum(PatronCount)  AS TANF, '' AS Foster, ''   AS FDPIR, ''    AS Homeless, '' AS Migrant, ''  AS Runaway, 
        '' AS HeadStart, '' AS EvenStart, ''    AS DirectCertified,  '' AS NoApplication, '' AS FreeIncome, '' AS ReducedIncome, 
        ''  AS RefusedBenefits,''   AS DeniedIncome, '' AS DeniedVerification,  ''  AS DeniedNotValid, ''   AS TempFreeGrace, ''    AS TempReducedGrace, 
        ''  AS DeniedInactive, ''   AS DNQ, '' AS ExpiredGrace
        from FarEligibilityEnrollmentCounts fe 
        inner join AdmSites A on fe.AdmSiteID = A.AdmSiteID 
        where fe.FarStudentCaseID = 'B348D33C-5C32-4CFE-B508-1E0CE2A9D428'
        Group BY fe.AdmSiteID,A.SiteDescription
```

The query returns data that looks like this.

```
AE1EF8E3-A093-410D-A02A-2B6DB334C758    Dowell Middle School    0       0
0359AF48-882F-4D54-B39D-341B17D64403    Evans Middle School     0       0
0359AF48-882F-4D54-B39D-341B17D64403    Evans Middle School     0       1595
0359AF48-882F-4D54-B39D-341B17D64403    Evans Middle School     1045    0
```

I am trying to merge the 3 Evans Middle School columns so the end result should look like

```
AE1EF8E3-A093-410D-A02A-2B6DB334C758    Dowell Middle School    0       0
0359AF48-882F-4D54-B39D-341B17D64403    Evans Middle School     1045    1595
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use option with [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
 ;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT AdmSiteID, SiteDescription, sum(PatronCount) as SNAP, '' AS TANF
  FROM FarEligibilityEnrollmentCounts JOIN ...  
  GROUP BY AdmSiteID, SiteDescription 
  UNION 
  SELECT AdmSiteID, SiteDescription, '' as SNAP, sum(PatronCount)  AS TANF
  FROM FarEligibilityEnrollmentCounts JOIN ... 
  GROUP BY AdmSiteID, SiteDescription
  ) 
  SELECT AdmSiteID, SiteDescription, MAX(SNAP), MAX(TANF)
  FROM cte
  GROUP BY AdmSiteID, SiteDescription
```

Also you can try this script without excessive union

```
select fe.AdmSiteID,A.SiteDescription,
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN fe.FarStudentCaseID = '4FA4AED1-75C9-4CB4-9FF2-102C2D964CC1' THEN PatronCount END), 0) AS SNAP,
       ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN fe.FarStudentCaseID = 'B348D33C-5C32-4CFE-B508-1E0CE2A9D428' THEN PatronCount END), 0) AS TANF,
       '' AS Foster, ''   AS FDPIR, ''    AS Homeless, '' AS Migrant, ''  AS Runaway, 
       '' AS HeadStart, '' AS EvenStart, ''    AS DirectCertified,  '' AS NoApplication, '' AS FreeIncome, '' AS ReducedIncome, 
       '' AS RefusedBenefits,''   AS DeniedIncome, '' AS DeniedVerification,  ''  AS DeniedNotValid, ''   AS TempFreeGrace, ''    AS TempReducedGrace, 
       '' AS DeniedInactive, ''   AS DNQ, '' AS ExpiredGrace
from FarEligibilityEnrollmentCounts fe 
  inner join AdmSites A on fe.AdmSiteID = A.AdmSiteID       
Group BY fe.AdmSiteID,A.SiteDescription
```

Simple demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3c56/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
select  AdmSiteID
,       SiteDescription
,       sum(SNAP) as TotalSNAP
,       sum(TANF) as TotalTANF
,       ... Other Sums Here ...
from    (
        ...  Your Query With Unions Here ...
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        AdmSiteID
,       SiteDescription
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE(Guids VARCHAR(100),School VARCHAR(30),Snap INT,Tnaf INT)
INSERT INTO @tab
VALUES('AE1EF8E3-A093-410D-A02A-2B6DB334C758','Dowell Middle School',0,0)
  ,('0359AF48-882F-4D54-B39D-341B17D64403','Evans Middle School',0,0)
  ,('0359AF48-882F-4D54-B39D-341B17D64403','Evans Middle School',0,1595)
  ,('0359AF48-882F-4D54-B39D-341B17D64403','Evans Middle School',1045,0)

SELECT *
FROM @tab 

SELECT DISTINCT Guids
,School
      ,SUM(Snap) OVER(PARTITION BY Guids,School) AS TtlSnap
      ,SUM(Tnaf) OVER(PARTITION BY Guids,School) AS TtlTnaf
FROM @tab
ORDER BY School
```